# Avoiding the new Chromium Developer Tool's long running timer task

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ionic-framework, chromium

I am using ionic, I am trying to broadcast an event after an event. But the chrome browser is not allowing me to broadcast it off late due to the new update to defer long running tasks.
[Code And Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0guPm.jpg)

How can I avoid this new issue and still broadcast the events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that warning all the time, on multiple projects, and so far it hasn't meant much. Whatever event got postponed *will eventually fire*. So if your broadcast isn't working, there's likely something else wrong.

To verify, try running the same code in another browser. The warning is a Chrome/Chromium only feature, so far as I know.

There are a few SO answers about the warning itself, but none of them are great and even basic jQuery functions can trigger it, so right now I'm assuming it can be ignored in most situations.